# Using regex with HTML

Tags: regex

I have the string `<option value=/digital/collections/newsouth62.html>1862</option>`
and I want to fetch only the `1862` from the above string using a regular expression.

Comment: Please read this: http://tinyurl.com/so-hints

Comment: You can [google](http://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=regex+tutorial) for things like this.

Comment: This is trivial to answer, but honestly it seems like you have put zero effort into trying AFAICT.  Could you make a few attempts and post what you did?

Comment: @Oded, thanks for that link, first time I saw it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
pattern = "|<option.*?>(.*?)</option>|";
```